# Is $\{ V_{H,\varepsilon} \mid \varepsilon> 0, H\in \wp_{<\omega}(X)\}$ a filter over $\mathbb C^X$?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, filters

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $\mathbb{C}^X$ be the space of functions $X\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. It's easy to define operations wich makes $\mathbb{C}^X$ into vector space. Let $H\subset X$ be a finite set ( $H\in\wp_{<\omega}(X)$). For some $\varepsilon>0$, define
    $$V_{H,\varepsilon} := \{ f\in \mathbb{C}^X \mid x\in H \Rightarrow \|f(x)\| \leqslant \varepsilon\}.$$

I wanna see if the set  $$\mathscr B := \{ V_{H,\varepsilon} \in \wp(\mathbb C^X) \mid \varepsilon> 0, H\in \wp_{_{<\omega}}(X)\}$$
is a filter in $\mathbb C^X$. I guess that some hypothesis are missing, like $X$ beeing compact or whatever, having trouble to prove that $U\supset V\in \mathscr B\Rightarrow U\in \mathscr B$.

Comment: This isn't a filter because it's not closed under supersets. It is, however, as the symbol $\mathcal B$ suggests, a filter base. Indeed, it's a base for the neighborhood filter of the zero function in $\mathbb C^X$ with respect to the product topology (product of $X$-indexed family of copies of $\mathbb C$ with the usual topology on $\mathbb C$).

Comment: Yeah, my guesses were indeed right hahaha That makes much more sense now, thanks. The notes prove that, and use only "filter" to describe (i was like "wtf is he talking ?"). With that filter base, i can make $\mathbb C^X$ into a TVS, right ?.

Comment: Yes, the product topology makes $\mathbb C^X$ a topological vector space.

Answer (score 0):

The collection $\mathcal{B}$ is only a filter base: if $V_{H,\varepsilon}$ and $V_{H',\varepsilon'}$ are two members, their intersection contains $V_{H \cup H', \min(\varepsilon, \varepsilon')} \in \mathcal{B}'$ and all members of $\mathcal{B}$ are non-empty (they all contain the constant $0$-function, e.g.).

These are in fact a standard filter base for the neighbourhoods for that $0$-function when $\Bbb C^X$ gets the product topology as a power of $\Bbb C$ and defines a TVS-topology in the usual way.